# how to select a specific date from a hive table

Tags: hive

I am trying to do a very elementary search for all the rows of a table for a particular date in a hive.

My table format is as follows:

create table table1
(
id text,
col1 text
);

The values of id are irrelevent, but the values of the col1 are datetime with YYYY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss GMT-0000.

```
select count (*) from table1 where unix_timestamp(col1,"yyyy/MM/dd")="2016/07/07";
```

this column col1 is in the string format and holds data like "2016/01/01 03:04:05 GMT-0000"

I am getting 0 rows, even though there are should be like a 100 rows with that date. I am unsure what is the version of hive I have. Please show me the light.

Thanks!

Comment: Try  select count (*) from table1 where col1 like "%2016/07/07";

Comment: @rUCHit31 Your suggestion worked with columns that are in a datetime/timestamp format. But it seems to be failing a column where it is a string.

Comment: like works well with string can you give your schema, I ll try in my hive command line

Comment: made update to the question

Answer (score 0):

Use [substring_index](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) function  .

As there is space between date and time you can use it like below.

select count (*) from table1  substring_index(col1 , ' ', 1)

Answer (score 0):

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP(string)` return unix timestamp of that date string.

Here in your query you have compared timestamp with date string.

Your query should look like

```
select count (*) from table1 where from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col1,"yyyy/MM/dd")) = "2016/07/07" ;
```